# List View Fragment to Fragment trasaction with OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have two fragments.

```
public class ListNav extends Fragment
public class SwipeNav extends Fragment
```

I made list view with 'ListNav' Class. I want to transact fragment to SwipeNav Fragment with 'setOnItemClickListener' when click on any item of string array.
I get result when use following.

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_listView);
    inputS=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.tab_titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
         inputS.setText((String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(i));

        }
    });
```

But I need to click on items from string array on 'ListNav' and it will open the new fragment 'SwipeNav' which opens all items from same string arrays with swipe views.I want to show the same item from ListNav to the same item on SwipeNav.
For that I am unable to implement. I use below method but fails. Error message :
Unfortunately app stops.

```
            SwipeNav fragment = new SwipeNav();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = 
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_list, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

SwipeNav.java

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    myPagerAdapter = new 
    MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
```

Logcat Errors:

```
                Shutting down VM
                W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d09b20)
                E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090067  (..:id/nav_list) for fragment SwipeNav{529dd108 #2 id=0x7f090067}
                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1413)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SwipeNav.java is also within the Navigation menu. It opens all items with swipe views. There is no error on SwipeNav.

Comment: according to the exception, your activity's xml doesn't have a layout with the id of `nav_list`, and you are trying to load a fragment in that id

Comment: @ronginat both the java file are in the Navigation Menu. ListNav opens all items as list and SwipeNav opens all items from string array without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Is the view corresponding to `R.id.nav_list` is in the activity? If so your fragment can't find the view that's in the activity. Either throw a callback to activity and then replace the fragment from the activity or use `view.rootView.findViewById(R.id.nav_list)` to get the view and gives its ID.